# Create a timeline using equipment on/off state change

Tags: mysql, excel, timeline

I have a table that holds a list of dates/times that equipment has been on and off. This is held as :

```
date-time   |  equipment id  | state (1 or 0)
```

I am trying to create a timeline that shows when the equipment was operational as a line or bar of when it was on and nothing when it was off.
I am not experienced with SQL so I am not sure how to approach this. I can either try to create an end-date/time using the start of the next change of state but I am not sure is this is possible in MySQL.
I have tried to do this in excel using just the queried list but it only plots as single date/time points. I think I need some kind of duration. I have no idea how to proceed.
Any advice or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You could just change the chart type in Excel to a line chart?

Comment: I will still need an end date/time. I have tried xy scatter in excel but this also needs an end time and it also interpolates the gaps so I end up with one long line.
I would like to calculate the end date/time in mysql as this is too time consuming in excel with so many records. In excel I need to calculate the MIN date/time that is higher than the start date/time, is the same equipment type and the opposite state. This takes far too long for each record.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)


set @last_date = NULL;
select @last_date as start_date,
  date as end_date,
  case when state = 1 then @last_date := date end as ignore_me,
  case when state = 0 then (unix_timestamp(date) - unix_timestamp(@last_date)) / 60 end as duration
from status
where id = 1
order by date
```

Gives you output like this:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| start_date          | end_date            | ignore_me           | duration |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 2012-11-20 01:16:00 | 2012-11-20 01:00:00 | 2012-11-20 01:00:00 |     NULL |
| 2012-11-20 01:00:00 | 2012-11-20 01:15:00 | NULL                |  15.0000 |
| 2012-11-20 01:00:00 | 2012-11-20 01:16:00 | 2012-11-20 01:16:00 |     NULL |
| 2012-11-20 01:16:00 | 2012-11-20 01:20:00 | NULL                |   4.0000 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Take just the rows with a duration to excel:

```
select * from (
  ...
) foo
where duration is not null

+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
| start_date          | end_date            | ignore_me | duration |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
| 2012-11-20 01:00:00 | 2012-11-20 01:15:00 | NULL      |  15.0000 |
| 2012-11-20 01:16:00 | 2012-11-20 01:20:00 | NULL      |   4.0000 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
```